# MVC enum custom JSON serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I'm writing a web application (not API) using MVC.NET.
I would like to serialize enums in a way that each enum JSON object would include a `Value` field and a `DisplayName` field. The `DisplayName` would be loaded from an attribute which is defined over each enum value in the backend code.

I figured out how to do this by creating a `BaseController` class which inherits from `Controller`, and in that class override the `Json()` function. However, I would like to be able to do this without creating a `BaseController` and forcing all the existing controllers inherit from that. Any ideas?

If that's not possible, Is there a way to force all Controllers to inherit from `BaseController` in code?

Comment: Cool name for ASP.NET MVC > MVC.NET

Comment: Hm, a somewhat hackish solution is to convert your enum to some other C#/.NET type, say `Foo`, that serializes into the json you want. Then pass those `Foo`s into `Json()`.

Comment: @roliu Yeah but then its the same code i would need to write each time i use an enum on client side... I preffer to inherit from BaseController.

Comment: @UriAbramson I'm not intimately familiar with ASP.NET MVC, but there only seems like a few logical possibilities: 1) You don't use `Json()`, 2) You modify `Json()`s behavior, 3) You use `Json()`s existing behavior but pass in different inputs to get the desired outputs. I doubt (1) is a good idea. If (2) requires you to override the default behavior then inheriting from `BaseController` seems necessary. And (3) is the solution I suggested, but it's indeed ugly. There might be a cleaner pattern for (3), but I think inheriting from `BaseController` is pretty standard.

Comment: @roliu You are basically right, but I was hoping someone heard of a (4) Some MVC infrastructure support for custom JSON formatting...